# How to pass artifact build from gitlab ci to dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I need a way to pass a job artifact from gitlab ci to a Dockerfile, so I can copy it into a directory. What is the path where this artifact is located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Steps:

1. use `artifacts` at your stage.
2. use `dependencies` to pass dependencies to the current stage.
3. And you can see files in `Dockerfile`.

---

For example, I run the vueJS project, the main flow:

1. stage1: build. Run `npm run build:prod` in vueJS project

```yaml
build-dist:
  stage: build-dist
  image: node
  script:
    - npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
```

2. stage2: use `dependencies`

```yaml
build-docker:
  stage: build-docker
  image: docker:stable
  script:
    - docker build
  dependencies:
    - build-dist
```

3. stage3: copy dist to Dockerfile

```
FROM fholzer/nginx-brotli

COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dependencies`, the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies) also state that job artifacts are passed to the next job by default.

The artifacts from the previous jobs will be downloaded and **extracted** in the context of the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RUN --mount=type=secret`
[Build images with BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)

There is an example to show how to copy credentials into dockerfile
This dockerfile

```sh
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials \
        cat /root/.aws/credentials
```

This the CI

```sh
$ docker build -t test --secret id=aws,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .
```